# javascript controlling data loaded by jqueryajax from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript 
My Javascript code is not working on the data that is fetched from the other page searchworld.php
When I see the pagesource the fetched data is not appearing

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {

    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        var searchbox = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ searchbox;

        if(searchbox=='')
        {
        }
        else
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "worldsearch.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){

                    $("#display").html(html).show();

                }

            });
        }
        return false;    


    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript the simplest way for you to see if you get anything back is to see if you can alert( html ); the html source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".search").on("keyup", function() {
```

`.on()` causes your events to bind on newly added content loaded with AJAX

Comment: `equals brace` is less than `3`? Really...?

Comment: Well, ignoring that, your answer is incorrect; `.on()` doesn't bind to  dynamically added content, especially not in the example given. It can be used to delegate events, but that uses a different syntax.